# Using a sparse matrix versus numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, scikit-learn

I am creating some numpy arrays with word counts in Python: rows are documents, columns are counts for word X. If I have a lot of zero counts, people suggest using sparse matrices when processing these further, e.g. in a classifier. When feeding a numpy array versus a sparse matrix into the Scikit [logistic regression classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit), it did not seem to make much of a difference, however. So I was wondering about three things:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) says

  > a sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements are zero

  Is that an appropriate way to determine when to use a sparse matrix
  format - as soon as > 50 % of the values are zero? Or does it make
  sense to use just in case?
- How much does a sparse matrix help performance in a task like mine,
  especially compared to a numpy array or a standard list?
- So far, I collect my data into a numpy array, then convert into the
  csr_matrix in [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). Is that the right way to do it? I could not
  figure out how to build a sparse matrix from the ground up, and that
  might be impossible.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `scipy` sparse matrix package, and similar ones in MATLAB, was based on ideas developed from linear algebra problems, such as solving large sparse linear equations (e.g. finite difference and finite element implementations).  So things like matrix product (the `dot` product for numpy arrays) and equation solvers are well developed.

My rough experience is that a sparse `csr` matrix product has to have a 1% sparsity to be faster than the equivalent dense `dot` operation - in other words, one nonzero value for every 99 zeros. (but see tests below)

But people also  try to use sparse matrices to save memory.  But keep in mind that such a matrix has to store 3 arrays of values (at least in the `coo` format).  So the sparsity has to be less than 1/3 to start saving memory.  Obviously you aren't going to save memory if you first build the dense array, and create the sparse one from that.

The `scipy` package implements many sparse formats.  The `coo` format is easiest to understand and build.  Build one according to documentation and look at its `.data`, `.row`, and `.col` attributes (3 1d arrays).

`csr` and `csc` are typically built from the `coo` format, and compress the data  a bit, making them a bit harder to understand.  But they have most of the math functionality.

It is also possible to index `csr` format, though in general this is slower than the equivalent dense matrix/array case.  Other operations like changing values (especially from 0 to nonzero), concatenation, incremental growth, are also slower.

`lil` (lists of lists) is also easy to understand, and best for incremental building.  `dok` is a actually a dictionary subclass.

A key point is that a sparse matrix is limited to 2d, and in many ways behaves like the `np.matrix` class (though it isn't a subclass).

A search for other questions using `scikit-learn` and `sparse` might be the best way of finding the pros/cons of using these matrices.  I've answered a number of questions, but I know the 'sparse' side better than the 'learn' side.  I think they are useful, but I get the sense is that the fit isn't always the best.  Any customization is on the `learn` side.  So far the `sparse` package has not been optimized for this application.

---

I just tried some matrix product tests, using the `sparse.random` method to create a sparse matrix with a specified sparsity.  Sparse matrix multiplication performed better than I expected.

```
In [251]: M=sparse.random(1000,1000,.5)

In [252]: timeit M1=M*M
1 loops, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop

In [253]: timeit Ma=M.toarray(); M2=Ma.dot(Ma)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.28 s per loop
```

It is a size issue; for smaller matrix the dense `dot` is faster

```
In [255]: M=sparse.random(100,100,.5)

In [256]: timeit M1=M*M
100 loops, best of 3: 3.24 ms per loop

In [257]: timeit Ma=M.toarray(); M2=Ma.dot(Ma)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

But compare indexing

```
In [268]: timeit M.tocsr()[500,500]
10 loops, best of 3: 86.4 ms per loop

In [269]: timeit Ma[500,500]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 318 ns per loop

In [270]: timeit Ma=M.toarray();Ma[500,500]
10 loops, best of 3: 23.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: `In [257]: timeit Ma=M.toarray(); M2=Ma.dot(Ma)` doesn't this line take the time of converting a sparse matrix to dense matrix into account?

Comment: @NicholasZhi, yes as writen the `toarray` is part of the timing.  It's easy to time just the `Ma.dot` part if you think that's important.

Comment: `M*M` is the element-wise product, you need to compare sparse `dot` versus `M@M` and, as an interesting additional result, against the dense `np.dot(M, M, out)` for preallocated out. It’s two different operations.

Comment: @freistil90, when I wrote this `M*M` was matrix multiplication for sparse matrices..  Now there's an incomplete move to array like behavior.

Answer (score 18):

@hpaulj Your timeit is wrong, u are getting slow results cause of mapping sparse.random to numpy array (its slowish) with that in mind:

```py
M=sparse.random(1000,1000,.5)
Ma=M.toarray()

%timeit -n 25 M1=M*M
352 ms ± 1.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 25 loops each)

%timeit -n 25 M2=Ma.dot(Ma)
13.5 ms ± 2.17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 25 loops each)
```

To get close to numpy we need to have

```py
M=sparse.random(1000,1000,.03)

%timeit -n 25 M1=M*M
10.7 ms ± 119 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 25 loops each)

%timeit -n 25 M2=Ma.dot(Ma)
11.4 ms ± 564 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 25 loops each)
```

Comment: In your second timeit, Ma does not have the same values as M, right? Just confirming, I believe it shouldn't change the timing results of numpy.dot theoretically.

Comment: `M*M` is the element-wise product, you need to compare sparse `dot` versus `M@M` and, as an interesting additional result, against the dense `np.dot(M, M, out)` for preallocated `out`. It’s two different operations.

Answer (score 8):

> a sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements are zero
>   Is that an appropriate way to determine when to use a sparse matrix format - as soon as > 50 % of the values are zero? Or does it make sense to use just in case?

There is no general rule. It solely depends on your exact usage later on. You have to compute complexity of the model based on sparse matrix and without, and then you can find the "sweet spot". This will depend on both number of samples and dimension. In general, it often boils down to matrix multiplications of the form

```
X' W
```

where X is data matrix N x d, and W is some weight matrix d x K. Consequently "dense" multiplication takes `NdK` time, while sparse, assuming that your average per-row sparsity is p is `NpdK`. Thus if your sparsity is 50% you can expect nearly 2x faster operation. The harder part is to estimate the overhead of sparse access as opposed to heavily optimized dense based.

> How much does a sparse matrix help performance in a task like mine, especially compared to a numpy array or a standard list?

For a particular case of LR, this can be even few times faster than dense format, but in order to observe the difference you need lots of data (>1000) of high dimension (>100).

> So far, I collect my data into a numpy array, then convert into the csr_matrix in Scipy. Is that the right way to do it? I could not figure out how to build a sparse matrix from the ground up, and that might be impossible.

No, it is not a good approach. You can build it "from scratch" by for example first building a dictionary and then converting it etc. there are plenty of ways to construct sparse matrix without a dense one in the first place.

Comment: As an added note, the scipy documentation patrick links to actually has a few examples at the bottom of how to build a sparse matrix from scratch.

Comment: i know you're not supposed to post "thank you" comments, but that is an awesome answer & a very helpful comment. thanks guys.