# How to sum a list of sparse matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, addition, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently sum .csr_matrix sparse matrices stored in a list. Here's the issue:

```
List_=list_of_sparse matrices
I tried the following
result=np.sum(List_)
```

But I a getting error!

How can I do it? any help will be much appreciated

Comment: If you want real help, provide an actual example (e.g. [mcve]).  Also show the error with traceback!!!  That said, sparse matrices are not designed for efficient addition.  Math that doesn't change the sparsity is ok, since it can focus on the `data` attribute.  Matrix multiplication is also pretty good.  But things like sum require figuring out where nonzeros match etc.

Comment: One possibility is to convert all the matrices to `coo` format, then concatenate their attributes (rows, cols, data).  Make a new `coo` with these, and let the conversion to `csr` perform the addition.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop the list:

```
import numpy as np

List_ = [
    np.matrix([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]),
    np.matrix([[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]),
    np.matrix([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0]]),
]

sum_in = np.matrix(
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
)

for mat in List_:
    sum_in += mat

print(sum_in)
```

Comment: Thank @Ammar, but how can I create sum_in for sparse matrix?

Comment: You might have to convert it to a full matrix beforehand or look into the scipy package https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969886/using-a-sparse-matrix-versus-numpy-array

Answer (score 2):

For example you have a list of sparse matrix like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(111)

List_ = [csr_matrix(np.random.binomial(1,0.5,(2,2))) for i in range(3)]
```

If your array is huge, you should try not to convert it into dense (memory issues), there is already a addition method, so all you need to do is reduce:

```
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,List_)
result.toarray()
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

As mentioned by @AmmarAslam, you can convert it to dense and sum:

```
[i.toarray() for i in List_]
[array([[1, 0],
    [0, 1]]),
 array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]),
 array([[0, 0],
        [1, 0]])]
```

Summing this up is a matter of:

```
np.add.reduce([i.toarray() for i in List_])

array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```